# Navigation Controller Back Button Doesn't Show Text

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller, back-button, navigationbar

I want it to be like this:
[image]

But I have it like this:
[image]

I need the same "Back" text in the back button, but it shows just that damn icon.

Those are 2 identical navigation controllers, same push/pop, same initialization, but with a different back buttons.

I need help, otherwise I will go crazy tonight...

Comment: Was there a name on the previous Navigation Bar?

Comment: There wasn't on both. But if put a name (self.title) on both, then one with the "Back" button changes it to the name. And the one with just the icon does nothing.

Comment: What's the name of the navigation bar that causes problem?

Comment: I found out that setting @"" as the title on navigation bar seems to cause problems described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Back Button will get the title of the previous Navigation Bar.
If there is not, it would show the default "Back".
Your issue was that you put @"" as the title of your Previous Navigation Bar, so it renamed the Back Button with @"", which is seen as "blank".